# how to send the parameter to the javascript function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, parameters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function changetext(mypara)
{
    mypara.innerHTML="Ooops!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>var mypara = document.getElementById("para1");</script>
<h1 onclick="changetext(mypara)">Click this text to change the content of following   paragraph</h1>
<p id="para1"> this is a paragraph I would like to change </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to let user to click the heading to change the content of the paragraph, but I don't know the correct way of coding that. How to send the "mypara" parameter to myFunction() in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example almost works - the problem is when you execute this line:

```
var mypara = document.getElementById("para1");
```

The element you're refering to does not yet exist. You could fix it by just going inline:

```
<h1 onclick="changetext(document.getElementById('para1'))">...</h1>
```

Live example for this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw5CG/2/

or perhaps just pass the id to the method:

```
<h1 onclick="changetext('para1')">...</h1>
```

and change the method to do the `getElementById`:

```
function changetext(mypara)
{
    document.getElementById(mypara).innerHTML="Ooops!";
}
```

Live example for this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw5CG/1/

Comment: Jamiec, you are really very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The element doesn't exist yet when you're trying to get it.
Why not just get it in the event handler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function changetext() {
                document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "Ooops!";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 onclick="changetext()">Click this text to change the content of following   paragraph</h1>

        <p id="para1">this is a paragraph I would like to change</p>
    </body>

</html>
```